# IcCube - Automatically reload Report after Schema reload

Tags: iccube-reporting

If an IcCube schema is refreshed, the new data will be visible for a user only, if he makes a new login and visits the report again.
But of course, she doesn't know, that the schema is refreshed.
What is the best way to handle this?

Is there for example a way to notify the end user, when the schema underlying the open report is updated, with the option for the user to reload the content (but keep the current filtering)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate the Refresh Period in the report configurtion. The report will be updated each time the server receive new data.

Answer (score 0):

That activation has to be done in every single report?
or can it be configured centrally for all existing reports or at least for each new report?